# .click() jQuery method fails to trigger .execCommand('cut')

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, execcommand

There seems to be some innate security features that come with running `.execCommands()` in JavaScript.  Specifcally, when I manually click a `button`, the `cut` execCommand will fire just fine but when I attempt to trigger the very same event programmatically via the jQuery `.click()` method, it fails.

Please explain why it fails, although I suspect it is because it was not manually fired by the user.

Also, I would like to find a way to circumvent the forced manual input of an event before the execCommand fires.

The snippet below outlines the issue and there are already console logs that notifies what occurs.

To be clear, I am looking to invoke a **real click** programmatically (if possible).  I am ***not*** looking to create a psuedo-click or the illusion of a cut/paste.

```js
//Cut and Copy Commands - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en

//$('*').attr('contenteditable', 'true');

var copyEmailBtn = document.querySelector('.js-emailcopybtn');
copyEmailBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Select the email link anchor text  
  var emailLink = document.querySelector('.js-emaillink');
  $('a').focus();
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(emailLink);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  try {
    // Now that we've selected the anchor text, execute the copy command  
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copy email command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }

  // Remove the selections - NOTE: Should use
  // removeRange(range) when it is supported  
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
});

var cutTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacutbtn');

cutTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var cutTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-cuttextarea');
  cutTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('cut');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Cutting text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to cut');
  }
});

$('.js-textareacutbtn').click();
//$('button.js-textareacutbtn').focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Email me at <a class="js-emaillink" href="mailto:matt@example.co.uk">matt@example.co.uk</a>
</p>

<p>
  <button class="js-emailcopybtn">Text</button>
</p>

<p>
  <input class="js-cuttextarea" type='text' value="Hello I'm some text">
</p>

<p>
  <button class="js-textareacutbtn">Cut Textarea</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Something that might help is using [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) since it was designed to be function based on the current browser, and has a fairly easy to use interface for copy/pasting in JS